# Hazelcast keep running after application stops on Weblogic (and also Tomcat)

Tags: java, tomcat, weblogic, hazelcast

I have just been playing around to get what Hazelcast provides. There are only a few things using Hazelcast in the applcation.

On Weblogic server 10.3.6, I saw that there is something wrong on one of the Maps. It kept giving exception about no class definiton error even though it has been running maybe more than a few days without a problem. Then I stoppped the application on running 8 nodes on Oracle Weblogic. I assumed the Hazelcast clusters/instances would shutdown as well but even though the application stops on all the nodes of Weblogic, I saw Hazelcast merge exceptions on the logs (keep throwing).

I also test my spring based application on Tomcat 7, even though I shutdown the application, Hazelcast resists shutting down somehow.

Is it normal behaviour? How can we shutdown all Hazelcast instances even after shutting down the application?

Note that I call Hazelcast when my application starts, there is no special client, only 8 nodes of Weblogic server.

Edit: Here is the stacktrace of the migration problem

```
    SEVERE: Problem while reading DataSerializable, namespace: 0, id: 0, class: 'com.hazelcast.partition.impl.MigrationRequestOperation', exception: com.hazelcast.partition.impl.MigrationRequestOperation
com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: Problem while reading DataSerializable, namespace: 0, id: 0, class: 'com.hazelcast.partition.impl.MigrationRequestOperation', exception: com.hazelcast.partition.impl.MigrationRequestOperatio

 at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.DataSerializer.read(DataSerializer.java:120)
 at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.DataSerializer.read(DataSerializer.java:39)
 at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.StreamSerializerAdapter.toObject(StreamSerializerAdapter.java:65)
 at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.SerializationServiceImpl.toObject(SerializationServiceImpl.java:260)
 at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.NodeEngineImpl.toObject(NodeEngineImpl.java:186)
 at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicOperationService$OperationPacketHandler.loadOperation(BasicOperationService.java:638)
 at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicOperationService$OperationPacketHandler.handle(BasicOperationService.java:621)
 at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicOperationService$OperationPacketHandler.access$1500(BasicOperationService.java:614)
 at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicOperationService$BasicDispatcherImpl.dispatch(BasicOperationService.java:566)
 at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicOperationScheduler$OperationThread.process(BasicOperationScheduler.java:466)
 at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicOperationScheduler$OperationThread.processPriorityMessages(BasicOperationScheduler.java:480)
 at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicOperationScheduler$OperationThread.doRun(BasicOperationScheduler.java:457)
 at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.BasicOperationScheduler$OperationThread.run(BasicOperationScheduler.java:432)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.hazelcast.partition.impl.MigrationRequestOperation
 at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:297)
 at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:270)
 at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.findClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:64)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
 at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:179)
 at weblogic.utils.classloaders.ChangeAwareClassLoader.loadClass(ChangeAwareClassLoader.java:43)
 at com.hazelcast.nio.ClassLoaderUtil.tryLoadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:124)
 at com.hazelcast.nio.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:113)
 at com.hazelcast.nio.ClassLoaderUtil.newInstance(ClassLoaderUtil.java:66)
 at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.DataSerializer.read(DataSerializer.java:109)
 ... 12 more
Mar 16, 2015 5:31:29 PM com.hazelcast.spi.OperationService
```

Comment: Are you using Hazelcast embedded? Please, provide startup and shutdown code from your application?

Comment: @VikGamov; yes, I guess this is "embedded", I put hazelcast.jar into the classpath and use it as it was told in getting started part of the documentation. There is no "shutdown code", that's why I ask it. When I shutdown the application, doesn't it need to stop as it starts with the application?

Comment: @Yasim How do (and where) you start Hazelcast? Servlet? ServletContextListener?

Comment: By an init method of a spring bean which starts only once.

Answer (score 2):

The credible [Hazelcast docs](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html/overview.html) says:

> As a final step, if you are done with your client, you can shut it down as shown below. This will release all the used resources and will close connections to the cluster.

```
  client.shutdown();
```

which should be called in `destroy()` method of your bean:

```
 public class ExampleBean implements DisposableBean {
    public void destroy() {
      client.shutdown();
    }
 }
```

The exception you have pasted occurs due to the fact that your app class loader is destroyed upon shutdown of your app.